# how to change font family of captcha and give image in background of captcha?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

how to change font family of captcha and give image in background of captcha please tell me if any one to know about that. The code is below:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $change_time = md5(microtime());
    $get_value = substr($change_time, 0, 6);
    $_SESSION['value'] = $get_value;
    $create_image  = imagecreate(100, 30);
    imagecolorallocate($create_image, 51, 112, 183);
    $text_color  = imagecolorallocate($create_image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagestring($create_image, 50, 15, 7, $get_value, $text_color);
    header('Content:image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($create_image);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

- http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagettftext.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

---

I use it like this (extra file which is included):

```
session_name("page_session_name");
session_start();

header("Content-Type: image/png");      // Sets the Content of this file to an PNG-Image

$ttf = "./franconi.ttf";     // font path
$_SESSION["captcha_id"] = "";          // Clears the old value
$rnd = mt_rand(30000,90000);    // Generates a random number between 30000 and 90000

$_SESSION["captcha_id"] = $rnd;   // Sets the value of the session
$bild = imagecreatefromgif("bg.gif");     // Creates a new image from background file
$textColor = imagecolorallocate($bild, 255, 255, 255);              // Sets white text color
imagettftext($bild, 11, 10, 5, 20, $textColor, $ttf, $_SESSION["captcha_id"]); 

ImagePNG($bild);             // Output for the generated image
```

---

include it like this:

```
<img src="./path_to/captcha.php" title="Captcha" height="50" width="100"/>
```